# FK Column error - MVC Core 2 - SqlException: Invalid column name 'DepartmentID1'.

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have two simple classes with a Primary Key and FK relationship.

In the Sub_Department class, I get the error

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'DepartmentID1'.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__108_0(Task result)

Here is my code

```
 public class Departments_Category_Registration
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }              // This is the PK
    public Departments DepartmentID  { get; set; } // this is a FK
```

and my Departments class with the PK

```
    public class Departments
{
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
[Display(Name ="Departments")]
[Required]
    public string Department_Name { get; set; }
[Display(Name ="Departments")]
[Required]
    public string Description_Long { get; set; }
[Display(Name ="Short Description_Short")]
[Required]
    public string Description_Short { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

however if I update my db to change the FK to department1 it works, funny thing is that I never used 1 in my code, I had changed it from ID to DepartmentID (if that helps)

Secondly, I thought I ask, if its wise to create a separate controller for each model or not ?

Ehi

Comment: You have DepartmentID as Departments in your first class, but Departments is a class, and you are treating DepartmentID as an int . . . Did you mis-type the code here?

Comment: Yes, I am migrating from webforms to MVC and confused on how to get DepartmentID as a FK, I read online that I use it above, hence why I put it as so, If I change it to int, it works, but my question is how do I create a FK relationship ?

Comment: Hi. Please read [ask] & other [help] links & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Google error messages with & without your particular strings. Always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Create & give a [mcve]. Don't clarify in comments, edit your post. Ask one question per question, ask the question you want ask, not something else, and not in a comment, and if necessary in another post. Also your "however" paragraph is not clear. And see above re an MCVE for it.